# Python: matrix completion functions/library?

Tags: python, matlab, methods, matrix, prediction

Are there functions in python that will fill out missing values in a matrix for you, by using **collaborative filtering** (ex. alternating minimization algorithm, etc). Or does one need to implement such functions from scratch?

[EDIT]: Although this isn't a matrix-completion example, but just to illustrate a similar situation, I know there is an svd() function in Matlab that takes a matrix as input and automatically outputs the singular value decomposition (svd) of it. I'm looking for something like that in Python, hopefully a built-in function, but even a good library out there would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [numpy's linalg library](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html) to find a python SVD implementation

Comment: what about for matrix completion methods (i.e. collaborative filtering)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a library [fancyimpute](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fancyimpute/0.0.4). Also, sklearn [NMF](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.NMF.html)